# Updating Dictionary in a loop Python

Tags: python

I am creating records in `dict` data type in python. How can I add new items in the `dict` by using while loop as we do in `tuples` by using:

```
 tuple += (rec)
```

When I use this code it will add elements in the `tuple` no matter how much. How to perform the same task with a `dict`

```
while True:
    name = input('Student Name: ')
    while True:
        course = input('Course Name: ')
        courses.append(course)
        print('You have entered', len(courses), 'course(s)')
        ch_course = input('Would you like to add a new course [Y]or[N]: ')
        if ch_course == 'y' or ch_course == 'Y':
            continue
        else:
            stdrec = ({name : courses})
            break
    ch_name = input('Would you like to add a new record [Y]or[N]: ')
    if ch_name == 'n' or ch_name == 'N':
        print(stdrec)
        break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to a `dict` named `stdrecs`, you would store a new key/value pair, i.e `stdrecs[name] = courses`. This would look like:

```
stdrecs = {}    
while True:
    name = input('Student Name: ')
    courses = []
    while True:
        course = input('Course Name: ')
        courses.append(course)
        print('You have entered', len(courses), 'course(s)')
        ch_course = input('Would you like to add a new course [Y]or[N]: ')
        if ch_course.upper() == 'Y':
            continue
        else:
            stdrecs[name] = courses
            break
    ch_name = input('Would you like to add a new record [Y]or[N]: ')
    if ch_name.upper() == 'N':
        print(stdrecs)
        break
```